# C# project doesnt realize the updates from WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF webservice and another c# project. I added the WCF webservice to my project to do some processes. But I changed a function's return type in webservice, then tried to update the webservice from the project, it still sees the old return type.

I deleted the webservice reference from my project and re-added back into the project, it still sees the old return type. Where does it cache these information?

Comment: did you rebuild the WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the `Web.Config` entry for you webservice URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running through IIS, sometimes this can hold onto the dll.

Here is everything i can think of that I'd try

1. Backup
2. Delete bin/obj folders in both projects
3. Restart IIS
4. Rebuild WCF project
5. Client project - Right click on the reference -> "Update References" and rebuild client project (possibly do the delete and re-add as you have done).
6. On a couple of occasions (in older versions), I've even had to close and re-open VS.

That can be a really frustrating issue on the odd occasion you hit it. HTH.

Comment: If that and @MHOOS ideas don't work, then I am out of ideas without seeing the projects. The only other thing that it has been before is the face-palmer of not actually looking at what I thought I was looking at (either code wise, or in line with Arshad's web.config post, such as referencing the test environment instead of dev). Sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the service and add it again those downloaded classes to your system should be deleted however if for some reason you recon they are there then do the following check:
Now go to the service reference folder and expand it. All the necessary classes and definition for constructing the proxy reside in the following folder:
...\Service References...

[image: Show All Files button]

You can check whether this folder gets emptied. When you re-add them you can check the reference file yourself to see whether new definitions are available.

[image: Service References]

Comment: @ArifYilmaz, if by removing the service and adding it again using above method your service data is not updated it is highly likely(almost certain) the service you are querying does not expose your newly expected data contracts. Use Visual Studio's built-in WCFTestClient.exe and query the service again.